# How to Return Difference of Successive Rows in a Column with Other Data (mySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fetching some transaction data from a mysql table like this:

```
SELECT bill_no as Document_No, bill_date as Trans_Date, bill_amount as Amount, 0 as Balance
FROM bill_table
WHERE consumer_name = 'John'
UNION
SELECT receipt_no as Document_No, receipt_date as Trans_Date, -receipt_amount as Amount, 0 as Balance
FROM receipt_table
WHERE consumer_name = 'John'
ORDER BY Trans_Date
```

Which results in something like this

```
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
|Document_No|Order_date|Amount|Balance|
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
|BILL58788  |2010-08-09|493   | 0     |
|BILL58789  |2010-08-10|789   | 0     |
|REC_12379  |2010-08-11|-1282 | 0     |
|BILL58788  |2010-08-12|1493  | 0     |
|BILL58788  |2010-09-01|4930  | 0     |
|REC_12380  |2010-10-02|-2000 | 0     |
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
```

This gives me all the bills & receipt details of John. All amounts are in same column, bill amounts are positive & receipt amounts are negative.

In the last column 'Balance', I want a total of successive amounts like this, calculated dynamically:

```
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
|Document_No|Order_date|Amount|Balance|
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
|BILL58788  |2010-08-09|493   | 493   |
|BILL58789  |2010-08-10|789   | 1282  |
|REC_12379  |2010-08-11|-1282 | 0     |
|BILL58788  |2010-08-12|1493  | 1493  |
|BILL58788  |2010-09-01|4930  | 6423  |
|REC_12380  |2010-10-02|-2000 | 4423  |
+-----------+----------+------+-------+
```

I know I can accomplish this in PHP after fetching the data but I want to do it mySQL itself.

Is it possible ? Please help.
Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MySQL, the easiest way to do this is using variables:

```
select Document_No, bill_date, bill_amount, 
       (@balance := @balance + bill_amount) as balance
from ((SELECT bill_no as Document_No, bill_date as Trans_Date, bill_amount as Amount
       FROM bill_table
       WHERE consumer_name = 'John'
      )
      UNION ALL
      (SELECT receipt_no as Document_No, receipt_date as Trans_Date, -receipt_amount as Amount
      FROM receipt_table
      WHERE consumer_name = 'John'
     )
    ) t cross join
    (select @balance := 0) const
ORDER BY Trans_Date;
```

Comment: That works beautifully. Thanks. I am not well versed with using variables in mySQL. Could you please tell me the purpose of:
    (select @balance := 0) const